# Custom required input

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a custom required input for a form where you only can put in 5 letters and
2 numbers?

Example: When you use required in a input and leave it blank, it will say "This field is required".

What I want: A custom input where you only can put 5 letters in and 2 numbers in.

Comment: I didnt fully understood your question, but this looks as it should be made using Javascript. Something like a function that will check the if (in the 5 first inputs of the keyboard) the character is a letter or not, and in the last two it will check if it is numbers.

Comment: [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern), but remember that all of this is client-side. In other words, you would want to also check once more on the server side. Also, to make things easier, consider splitting this into two input fields, one for the 5 letters and one for the 2 numbers.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. Someone with more time should find one.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're looking to use a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute? Use `[a-zA-z]{5}\d{2}` to match 5 letters and 2 numbers:

```html
<form>
  <button>click</button>
  <input pattern="[a-zA-z]{5}\d{2}" required>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `input` tag with the following attributes:

- [`required`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) set to `required`;
- [`pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) set to your regular expression: `[a-zA-z]{5}[0-9]{2}`.

*N.B.* the `pattern` attribute is supported by the following browsers: IE 10+, Edge 12+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 10+, Safari 10.1+, Opera 10+, iOS Safari 10.3+, [etc.](https://caniuse.com/input-pattern)

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('OK');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-z]{5}[0-9]{2}" required="required">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `pattern` attribute which expect a regular expression :

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-F]{5}[0-9]{2}">
```

Comment: This regular expression will match 5 uppercase chars (from ‘A’ to ‘F’) and 2 numbers. Instead the requirement is “5 letters and 2 numbers”.